# Since velocity is a relative quantity, does this mean magnetic force will act as an electrostatic force in a non-intertial frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, reference-frames

Assume there are two identical bodies (A & B) moving with same velocity, where body 'A' has some non-zero charge while 'B' is electrically neutral. If they come across a magnetic field. 'A' will go off route.

But since in B's frame, 'A' was stationery in the beginning and has now acquired an acceleration such that now there's a non-zero relative velocity and since A is a charged body, the only explanation is an electric field which its not(?)

I am having trouble understanding the non-inertial side of the magnetic force.

Comment: B would see A as accelerated, but there would be no reason to say the force was electrostatic.

Comment: Related - [How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0) and [Veritasium's 'How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work' - EXPLAINED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWiY5kVw9U4)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that fields transform according to Lorentz transformations.

> zero relative velocity and since A is a charged body, the only
> explanation is an electric field which its not(?)

Surprisingly, the answer to this question is yes. The Lorentz transformation on the electromagnetic field (or precisely $A^\mu$ 4-vector) will “add” an Electric field component that, in the other frame, will be consistent with the observed deflection.

Griffiths E&M Chapter 12 explains this in the detail that is required for a first time learner, so I will leave it to you to delve into the mathematics in detail.